# Aligning table-entries at \pm

Tags: tables, align, multicolumn

I have a table with multiple columns, where the entries have uncertainties attached to them. Is it possible to align the entries at the `\pm`-sign?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{clllllllll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 1} &              \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 2} &              \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 3} &               \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 4} &               \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 5} &              \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 6} &               \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 7} &              \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 8} &               \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 9} &              \multicolumn{1}{c}{Column 10} \\
\midrule
A  &     1.12 ± 2.32 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &    0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 &     0.00 ± 0.00 \\
B  &   -7.58 ± 24.03 &  -12.89 ± 27.25 &   -5.93 ± 26.02 &   -2.50 ± 26.30 &  -0.98 ± 25.44 &    2.61 ± 35.59 &  -11.96 ± 12.19 &   -2.64 ± 26.53 &  -24.07 ± 19.40 \\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT: I tried using the `siunitx`, but the uncertainties won't align a the decimal separator

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\scriptsize
\centering
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]   
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]           
}
\toprule
{Column 1} & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & {Column 4} & {Column 5} & {Column 6} & {Column 7} & {Column 8} & {Column 9} & {Column 10} \\
\midrule
A  &     1.12+-2.32 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &    0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 \\
B  &   -7.58+-24.03 &  -12.89+-27.25 &   -5.93+-26.02 &   -2.50+-26.30 &  -0.98+-25.44 &    2.61+-35.59 &  -11.96+-12.19 &   -2.64+-26.53 &  -24.07+-19.40 \\
B  &   -7.58+-24.03 &  -12.89+-27.25 &   -5.93+-26.02 &   -2.50+-26.30 &  -0.98+-25.44 &    2.61+-35.59 &  -11.96+-12.19 &   -2.64+-26.53 &  -24.07+-9.40 \\
\end{tabular}%
%}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

How do I align the uncertainties at the decimal separator?

Comment: Have a look at the siunitx package (and don't use resizebox for things which contain text, choose a suitable font size instead.)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I tried it out - see the OP with updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- your uncertainties have two digits after the decimal separator, this means that you need to use `(2.2)` instead of `(2)` in the `table-format` to allocate enough space
- us `\pm` or `+-` to denote the uncertainties in your input
- unrelated to LaTeX, but please check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Significant_figures_in_writing_uncertainty

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\scriptsize
\centering
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  c
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]   
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]
  S[table-format=-2.2(2.2)]           
}
\toprule
{Column 1} & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & {Column 4} & {Column 5} & {Column 6} & {Column 7} & {Column 8} & {Column 9} & {Column 10} \\
\midrule
A  &     1.12+-2.32 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &    0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 &     0.00+-0.00 \\
B  &   -7.58+-24.03 &  -12.89+-27.25 &   -5.93+-26.02 &   -2.50+-26.30 &  -0.98+-25.44 &    2.61+-35.59 &  -11.96+-12.19 &   -2.64+-26.53 &  -24.07+-19.40 \\
\end{tabular}%
%}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For some odd reason, this example doesn't align on Overleaf - but it works in a local Latex-compiler. Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: @TylerD Seems to work fine on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/fsjfmswcxsmy#ff71f1 Are you using tl2023 or an older version? (check the left sidebar in overleaf)

Comment: It's very odd - it works with TeX Live 2022, but doesn't align with 2023

Comment: I know I'm asking for a lot here, but is it possible to align the uncertainties on their `.`-separator? Thanks

Comment: @TylerD The uncertainties are automatically aligned on their decimal separator, you can see it in column #2

Comment: But what about cases where the uncertainties have less/more than two digits? E.g., 9.78 or 1.23. In those cases they don't get aligned

Comment: `2.32` has less digits than `24.03` and they are aligned.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the OP with an example and image of the issue

Comment: Works fine for me with an up-to-date version of siunitx https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW2fQ.png

Comment: Thanks, that's odd - I see the misalignment on Overleaf as well. Is there a way to circumvent it?

Comment: Overleaf is a couple of months behind the current version. They usually only update once a year.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz solution ... Differences are:

- written are all tolerances, also `0.00`
- two version of `siunitx` settings (MSE consider only first six columns of table)
- for rotating of table is used `sidewaystable` of `\rotating` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         retain-zero-uncertainty,
         table-alignment-mode = format,
         %tight-spacing,
         }
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {Q[c] X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(2.2)}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(2.2)}]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(1.2)}]}
                       },
...
\end{verbatim}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty,
         retain-zero-uncertainty,
         table-alignment-mode = format,
         %tight-spacing,
         }
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z},
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {Q[c] X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(2.2)}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(2.2)}]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(2.2)}]}
                       },
             row{1}  = {guard, c, font=\bfseries}
             }
column 1    & column 2      & column 3      & column 4      & column 5          \\
A           &  1.12+-2.32   &   0.00+-1.1   &   0.00+-0.0   &  0.00             \\
B           & -7.58+-24.03  & -12.89+-27.25 &  -5.93+-26.02 & -2.50+-26.30      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{verbatim}
\sisetup{mode=text,
         retain-zero-uncertainty,
         separate-uncertainty,
         %tight-spacing,
        }
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z},
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {c    X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(4)}]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]}
                       },
...
\end{verbatim}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{mode=text,           
         retain-zero-uncertainty,
         separate-uncertainty, 
         %tight-spacing,
        }
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z},
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {Q[c] X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(4)}]
                        *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]}
                       },
             row{1}  = {guard, c, font=\bfseries}
             }
column 1    & column 2      & column 3      & column 4      & column 5          \\
A           &  1.12+-2.32   &  0.00+-1.1    &   0.00+-0.0   &  0.00             \\
B           & -7.58+-24.03  & -2.89+-27.25  &  -5.93+-26.02 & -2.50+-26.30      \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
\sisetup{mode=text,
         retain-zero-uncertainty,
         separate-uncertainty
        }
\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,2,Z}, 
             colsep=1pt,
             colspec = {@{}
                        Q[c] X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]
                             X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(4)}]
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=-1.2(4)}]}
                             X[c, si={table-format= 1.2(4)}]
                        *{3}{X[c, si={table-format=-2.2(4)}]}
                       @{}},
             row{1}  = {guard, c, font=\bfseries}
             }
col. 1      & column 2      & column 3      & column 4      & column 5 
            & column 6      & column 7      & column 8      & column 9
            & column 10     \\
A           &   1.12+-2.32  &   0.00+-0.00  &   0.00+-0.00  &   0.00+-0.00 
            &   0.00+-0.00  &   0.00+-0.00  &   0.00+-0.00  &   0.00+-0.00 
            &   0.00+-0.00 \\
B           &  -7.58+-24.03 & -12.89+-27.25 &  -5.93+-26.02 &  -2.50+-26.30 
            &  -0.98+-25.44 &   2.61+-35.59 & -11.96+-12.19 &  -2.64+-26.53 
            &  -24.07+-19.40 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]